# Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pi_digits.txt'

Tags: python, exception, filenotfounderror

I'm trying to open a file and print out the contents, but when I run the code, I get the error

```
Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pi_digits.txt'
```

Here is the code for the file trying to access the txt file:

```
"""A simple file reader that accesses the py_digits text file and prints it out."""

# utf-8 is the standard encoding for txt files.
with open('pi_digits.txt', encoding='utf-8') as file_object:
    contents = file_object.read

print(contents)
```

And it's not a typo:

[image]

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct.

However the environment which calls the code is not.

The output of [getcwd()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd)
matters a great deal, since you're using a relative pathname.
You can `print` the current working directory as a debugging aid,
to better understand what is happening on your system.
Consider issuing a [chdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir)
to the proper directory, prior to attempting the open.

Alternatively, you might prefer to replace the relative pathname
with an absolute pathname:
`r"C:\some\where\pi_digits.txt"`

Comment: thanks for the help. Unfortunately, I don't really understand what a chdir is, or what getcwd() does. Could you explain further?

Comment: The link explained to you that it is "the current working directory". It sounds like you did not `import os` and did not attempt to follow the `print(os.getcwd())` advice. If you're not familiar with using `cd /some/where` to change directory, then I don't think it's likely the StackOverflow Q&A site will be a good match for you. Recommend you visit your local public library and ask for some introductory material on computer literacy and using the command line.